# Get referrer in Apex Visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex-code

Is it possible to get the referrer from a salesforce page that im editing in visualforce?

Im using the following APEX method

```
return ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl();
```

... the above only returns the current url and the previous or referrer

Answer (score 10):

```
public String getReferer(){
   return ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer');
}
```